# Collecting a value of a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

I'm using the [KISS](https://github.com/ampledata/kiss) Python module to collect data from the serial communications port.
This module has a function that returns the value of the values obtained from the serial port. The lines of code, obtained the source code of the module are the following:

```
for frame in frames:
    if len(frame) and ord(frame[0]) == 0:
        self.logger.debug('frame=%s', frame)
        self.logger.debug('hola soy el logger debug')

        if callback:
            callback(frame)
```

I'm trying to store the value of frame in a variable. I need to do in a thread that I created through inheritance an object of class `QThread`. I am making an application using PyQt4.

The class is as follows:

```
class OperativeKISSThread(KISSThread):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        KISSThread.__init__(self, parent)

    def doWork(self):
        prueba.read(callback=self.catchValue(frame))
        return True

    def catchValue(self, frame):
        print frame
```

When I run the above code I get the following screen output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_client_amp.py", line 432, in run
    success = self.doWork(self.kissTNC)
  File "_client_amp.py", line 452, in doWork
    prueba.read(callback=self.catchValue(frame))
NameError: global name 'frame' is not defined
```

What changes would be made in my code to get the value of frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback should be specified using just the function name, like:

```
def doWork(self, prueba):
    prueba.read(callback=self.catchValue)
    return True
```